# How to periodically save the last line of a program's output?

Tags: shell, unix, redirect, command-line

I run a program that generates a line of output every second. Each time a new line is generated I need to save it (and only it) into a particular text file. When a new line is generated the file must be overwritten with the new line.

I think it must be very simple solution but I can't figure it out using my poor knowledge of the shell commands.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would be one possible solution

```
./your_program | (while true; do read tmp && echo "$tmp" > $file; done)
```

where `$file` is your file.

Comment: This will never terminate!  `while read tmp; do echo "$tmp" ...` would be better.

Answer (score 2):

```
... | awk '{ print > "output"; close( "output" )}'
```

will truncate the output file with each new line of output.